# Is Wrapping intval() Around esc_attr() Redundant for Escaping Input?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, post-meta, escaping

My gut tells me wrapping esc_attr() in intval() is redundant when it comes to escaping input, but I would like to double-check.

Also: considering that `<option value="">- select no. -</option>` is hardcoded/value is null, that chunk of input wouldn't need to be escaped, correct?

Here is my current code set-up:

```
        <select name="_number">
        <option value="">- select no. -</option>
            <?php
            $savedNo = intval( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_number', true ) );
            for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
                echo '<option value="'
                    . intval(esc_attr($x)) . '"'
                    . ($x === $savedNo ? ' selected="selected"' : '' )
                    . '>'
                    . 'No. ' . intval(esc_attr($x))
                . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [WordPress documentation for `esc_attr` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/#return), it is returning a string value. So, If you need to have the integer value, you need using `intval` function. **But**, when you want to display that value or put it as part of markup, it doesn't make sense.

Escape functions are useful for outputting and printing values. If you want to save a value in the database, the data type is a matter and you may need to use `intval` function alongside [sanitization](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/).

Answer (score -1):

In your case you don't need any of these functions on `$x`, because its values are created by `for` loop and are safe.

Comment: Why would a loop make it safe?

Comment: @kaiser What is possible scenario in OP example how `$x` value may get compromised? It is not user input, it is assigned by loop itself and used only in loop scope. Maybe I am wrong, but I really want to understand how in this case it can be anything else than integer?

Comment: Open your dev-tools, change the `value` of an `option` and you got user generated input.

Comment: @kaiser Sure, and it MUST be escaped or otherwise considered unsafe when you are processing POST request from user. But have you seen OP example? `$x` value there is not received from user input and could not be changed, no matter what he/she does in dev-tools or other way. Escaping in THIS case is just unnecessary operation.